# How do I append an additional path to a nested object in my JSON file, with the first half of the path being stores in a variable?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

The full JSON path (which does work when manually inserted) is `data.clients.clientID_1.users.userID_2.userItems.annualLeave`

I have used React Context to store `data.clients.clientID_1` in a variable. This is then brought into my child component stored in the variable:

`const {data} = useContext(DataContext)` - this works fine.
But how do I append the remaining `.users.userID_2.userItems.annualLeave` after this.

I am trying to get the the full path into the variable of `processedData` below.

Thanks.

```js
 const { data } = useContext(DataContext);

  const processedData = [data].users.userID_2.userItems.annualLeave;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following 3rd party to handle these things easily https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-path

It will allow you to access the paths written as strings.
For example:

```
objectPath.get(data, "users.userID_2.userItems.annualLeave")
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
use eval()
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval


const { data } = useContext(DataContext);

const processedData = eval(data).users.userID_2.userItems.annualLeave;
```